# xaxis category not plotting the values correctly with multiple series highcharts dynamically populate using php-mysql

Tags: plot, highcharts, categories

Am using highcharts to populate my chart which fetch the data from mysql db and the category for xaxis has been fetched from the db and placed after sorting.My chart have multiple series.The data values for the chart is below:
[{"name":"0.1 ng/ml","data":[["24 Hr",1.2]]},{"name":"1 ng/ml","data":[["24 Hr",2.2]]},{"name":"10 ng/ml","data":[["24 Hr",5.3]]},{"name":"3.5 ng/ml","data":[["24 Hr",3]]},{"name":"5 ng/ml","data":[["240 Min",2.2],["480 Min",3.1],["24 Hr",2.63],["48 Hr",8.1]]}]

so by taking these values it plots the '24 Hr' wrongly in the '240 Min' section .

Please help me to solve this.

function InitHighChart1(v1)
{
    $("#chart1").html("Wait, Loading graph1...");

```
var options = {
    chart: {type: 'line',
        renderTo: 'chart1',
    },colors: ['#058DC7', '#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', '#FF9655', '#FFF263', '#6AF9C4'],
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Pubmed Id: '+v1,
        x: -20
    },

        xAxis: {categories:<?php echo $_SESSION["cat"]; ?>,

        minPadding: 0.05,
        maxPadding: 0.05,
         title: {
    enabled: true,
    text: 'Time Point'

}

    },
    tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true,
    headerFormat: '<small>Time Point:{point.key}</small><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td>Dosage:</td><td style="color: {series.color}">{series.name}: </td>' +
        '<td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.y} </b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    enabled: true,
        crosshairs: {
            color: 'blue',
            dashStyle: 'solid'
        }

    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: true
        }
    },
    series: [{}]


};

$.ajax({
    url: "jdata.php",
    data: 'show=impressions',
    type:'get',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){

                           var getSeries = data;
                            options.series = getSeries;
                 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);         
    }
});
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuzjC.png)

Comment: Hi Meena Vinay, I reproduced your code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/csb86aw0/, and everything seems to work correctly. Could you provide me with an array of categories?

Comment: No the plotting of categories is not correct in the x axis...means its not in order

Comment: The order depends on the `categories` array: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qm3x1osh/

Comment: The categories are {'240 Min','480 Min','24 Hr','48 Hr'}.The plotting is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

String values in the data array are treated as a point name. 
You need to set them as numerical values:

```
series: [{
    "name": "0.1 ng/ml",
    "data": [
        [2, 1.2]
    ]
}, {
    "name": "1 ng/ml",
    "data": [
        [2, 2.2]
    ]
}, {
    "name": "10 ng/ml",
    "data": [
        [2, 5.3]
    ]
}, {
    "name": "3.5 ng/ml",
    "data": [
        [2, 3]
    ]
}, {
    "name": "5 ng/ml",
    "data": [
        [0, 2.2],
        [1, 3.1],
        [2, 2.63],
        [3, 8.1]
    ]
}]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.data

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sfnq1b8m/

Comment: The numerical values are not applicable.Its a dynamic chart.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.But I cannot give the numerical value as the time point order of the chart is known only after once its filled with data.

Comment: Hi Meena Vinay, Ok, so you need to preprocess your data, please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d6k2rcLt/

Comment: Hi ,still am not able to correct it.Instead of numerical values is there any option to give string value. ie instead of 0,1,2,3.....time point values '30 min','60 Min','120 Min' .....

Comment: Hi @Meena Vinay, there is one more way out - you can add all names of points to first series in the correct order with null `y` values - example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gLeb18xn/